# How to specify when branch NOT (branch name) in jenkinsfile?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

How can I specify something like the following in my Jenkinsfile?

*when branch not x*

I know how to specify branch specific tasks like:

```
stage('Master Branch Tasks') {
        when {
            branch "master"
        }
        steps {
          sh '''#!/bin/bash -l
          Do some stuff here
          '''
        }
}
```

However I'd like to specify a stage for when branch is not master or staging like the following:

```
stage('Example') {
    if (env.BRANCH_NAME != 'master' && env.BRANCH_NAME != 'staging') {
        echo 'This is not master or staging'
    } else {
        echo 'things and stuff'
    }
}
```

However the above does not work and fails with the following errors:

```
WorkflowScript: 62: Not a valid stage section definition: "if 

WorkflowScript: 62: Nothing to execute within stage "Example"
```

Note source for my failed try: https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#flow-control

Answer (score 116, accepted):

With this [issue](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-41185) resolved, you can now do this:

```
stage('Example (Not master)') {
   when {
       not {
           branch 'master'
       }
   }
   steps {
     sh 'do-non-master.sh'
   }
}
```

Comment: Can we have this condition for all the stages at one place instead of putting it in every stage?

Answer (score 68):

You can also specify multiple conditions (in this case branch names) using `anyOf`:

```
stage('Example (Not master nor staging)') {
   when {
       not {
          anyOf {
            branch 'master';
            branch 'staging'
          }
       }
   }
   steps {
     sh 'do-non-master-nor-staging.sh'
   }
}
```

In this case `do-non-master-nor-staging.sh` will run on all branches **except** on *master* and *staging*.

You can read about built-in conditions and general pipeline syntax [here](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/).

Comment: Thank you for this, I had multiple branches in the not but it would only take one child condition

Answer (score 25):

The link from your post shows an example with the scripted pipeline syntax. Your code uses the declarative pipeline syntax. To use the scripted pipeline within declarative you can use the script step.

```
stage('Example') {
    steps {
        script { 
            if (env.BRANCH_NAME != 'master' && env.BRANCH_NAME != 'staging') {
                echo 'This is not master or staging'
            } else {
                echo 'things and stuff'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who want to use with env values and in case of declarative pipeline and you have dynamic branch fetching then you can define your own variables globally and use like below.[The variable "deployBranch" needs to be declared before pipeline and updated in a stage earlier to current stage or before using evaluation ]

```
            stage ('checkout-NonMaster') {
                when {
                    not {
                        environment(name: "deployBranch", value: "master")
                    }
                }
                steps {

                        <anything goes here like groovy code or shell commands>
                }
            }
```