# Jenkins: How to skip a specific stage in a multibranch pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, multibranch-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

We have "stage (build)" on all our branches.  Temporarily how can we skip this stage to run on all our branches in multibranch pipeline.  I know one solution is use when condition on stage and ask all developers to pull that branch into their branch.  But thats lot of work and coordination.  Instead I am looking for a global configuration where we can simply skip the stage by name on any branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you keep the Jenkinsfile alongside the code, but want to change how the Jenkinsfile runs from an administrative point of view.

You could store this stage in a separate (version control flavor of preference) repository.  Before you execute the stage, load in the repository then load in the script file and within the stage execute a method defined in that file.

Alternatively, add a parameter to the build job (this assumes you aren't setting parameters via options in the Jenkinsfile) that is a boolean to use or skip the stage and you can modify the project configuration when you want to turn it on or off

Answer (score 0):

What about this approach ?

```
  stage('build') { 

    if(buildFlag=="disable"){
      //jump to next stage
      return;
    }
    //do something
  }
```

**buildFlag** could be

- a simple var in the same pipeline
- a global var configured in jenkins. You could set **disabled** temporarily to skip **build** stage and change to **enabled** to restore to normalcy

Also you could set the status to failure, instead of return :

```
currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
```

Or throw an exception and exit the entire job or pipeline.

Comment: It is not possible to do this. 
WorkflowScript: 79: Not a valid stage section definition: "if(buildFlag){

Comment: Did you create the variable? This snippet works in a pipeline script or declarative pipeline. Don't blame others (downvote) for your incompetence.

Comment: Idont blame you, bu It doesn´t work, you must enclose it in stage('stage name') { steps { script { if(condition) { } } } }

Answer (score 0):

One option is to skip the body of the stage if the condition is met. For example:

```
  stage('Unit Tests') {
    steps {
      script{
        if (env.branch.startsWith(releaseBranch)} {
           echo 'Running unit tests with coverage...'
        } else {
           // run actual unit tests
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

The only downside is that the UI will show the "green box" for this step - even though it effectively did nothing.

If you want to remove the stage completely for the branch, use a [when](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#when) directive.

```
stage('deploy') {
        when {
            branch 'production'
        }
        steps {
            echo 'Deploying'
        }
 }
```

Bonus: You can also specify a "when not" directive as well. See [How to specify when branch NOT (branch name) in jenkinsfile?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45007229/1620112)